# How to execute this SQL Query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I am having following scenario

```
Drop Table #Temp
Create Table #Temp(name1 text, name2 text)

Insert INTO #Temp Values ('test','test')
Insert INTO #Temp Values ('test','test')

Insert Into #Temp1 Select * From 
(
;With CTE as (
 Select * from #Temp
 ) 
 select * from CTE
)
```

I know we can't use `CTE` as subquery .. but for hard time I don't know exact syntax of subquery since it is being provided by other system.

just image this

```
 Insert Into #Temp1 Select * From 
    (
     "Query Provided by Other System"
    )
```

So I don't have any control on subquery ("**Query Provided by Other System**").. And I have also tried dynamic sql query like

```
Declare @subquery nvarchar(max)

set @subquery=';With CTE2 as ( Select * from #Temp) select * from CTE2'

INSERT INTO #Temp1 From (EXEC sp_executesql @subquery)
```

This also gives error...

**More Things to know**:

i)I don't know about what are the columns will sub query returns

ii)And I don't have any control in sub query . like what is syntax of subquery and how it looks like?

so from these things,  even I can't use dynamic sql (`EXEC sp_executesql`).because I don't know what will happen if `@subquery` itself contains dynamic sql.

Please help anyone...

Comment: You should not prefix the `WITH` with `;`. The `;` is there to define the **end** of a statement. The usual (bad) habit to prefix `with` with `;` is only there to ensure the **previous** statement was terminated properly.

Comment: How are you getting subquery?

Comment: the is a pre-defined or stored query in xml

Comment: You might be able to use some variation of OPENQUERY http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188427%28v=sql.100%29.aspx or OPENROWSET http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190312.aspx.

Answer (score 1):

Use like this, with dynamic sql. It will work...

```
Insert Into #Temp1 
EXEC sp_executesql @subquery
```

Comment: yes but, I am getting this error Msg 208, Level 16, State 0, Line 12
Invalid object name '#Temp1'.

Comment: I don't have pre created table #Temp1 .. need to create this dynamically

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below syntax

```
;With CTE as (
    Select * from #Temp
) 
Insert Into #Temp1 
Select * 
From (
    select * from CTE
) t
```

or if you don't have already created the #Temp1 table, use below code. It will automatically create the #temp1 table according to the selected fields

```
;With CTE as (
    Select * from #Temp
) 
Select * 
Into #Temp1 
From (
    select * from CTE
) t
```

Besides syntax, you can simplify above SQL code as follows

```
;With CTE as (
    Select * from #Temp
) 
Insert Into #Temp1 
Select * 
From CTE
```

or better

```
Insert Into #Temp1 
Select * from #Temp
```